# Why does JavaMail use System.getProperties() ?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, system-properties

Why do we need to add the properties like

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); // added this line
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
    props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");


Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
```

to the system properties to send a mail. Why should it be specifically system properties?

Comment: How can things like your username, password be defaults?

Comment: @adarshr: that was not what I meant. I just wanted to know why it is added to the system properties.

Comment: It is just a way to send a large number of parameters to a method.

Comment: The question is perfectly valid. Why has it been downvoted? Most examples (and even the official JavaMail docs) use `System.getProperties()` instead of `new Properties()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't actually need to add them to the system properties.

If you create a new Properties instance and populate it with your attributes it will still work just the same.

Comment: but still why is it always added to the system properties. Generally to set a property the setProperty method is called. What is the puProperty method.

Comment: Try `Properties props = new Properties();` instead

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, they don't need to be system properties. But, the following may be the reason why many examples show it this way: The Java Mail package supports a large number of settings/debug options.  For example, https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html lists 50 different settings for the SMTP provider alone.

Suppose you want to set this option: "mail.smtp.ssl.checkserveridentity". If you use the System properties as your starting point, then you can restart your Java process with

```
-Dmail.smtp.ssl.checkserveridentity=true
```

to change the option. If you build up your Properties object yourself from scratch, then you might need a code change to set the option.

Answer (score 2):

They do NOT need to be System Properties. They can be [java.util.Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).